# How to fix ASMX WebService causing StackOverflowException in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll when viewed in Browser

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asmx

I have a web application with asmx web service Visual Studio 2012 converted to Visual Studio 2015.
In VS 2015 when ran in local IIS and viewing asmx in browser the site crashes.  In debug I found unhandled exception:

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred > in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to the WebService derived class.
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

There is a limitation on the number of methods it can handle.  The max appears to be 226.